# Node-Postgres Connect Error: EADDRNOTAVAIL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, database-connection, port

I don't understand why I can't connect to Postgres using the node-postgres client but when using Navicat for Postgres with the same credentials, I can. Here is my code:

```
var client = new _pg.Client({
            user: 'un',
            password: 'pwd',
            database: 'postgres',
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 5432,
            ssl: true
        });
client.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('connect err object');
            console.log('err = ' + JSON.stringify(err));
            return cb(err, undefined);
        }
        console.log('no error connecting');
        client.query('select * from lookup', function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('query err object');
                console.log('err = ' + JSON.stringify(err));
                return cb(err, undefined);
            }
            console.log('query exec successfully');
            console.log('result = ' + JSON.stringify(result));
            return cb(undefined, client);
        });
    });
```

The connect callback errors out with:

```
err = {"code":"EADDRNOTAVAIL","errno":"EADDRNOTAVAIL","syscall":"connect"}
```

I ran OSX Network utility and it indicates the port is open:

```
Port Scan has started…

Port Scanning host: 127.0.0.1

     Open TCP Port:     5432        postgresql
Port Scan has completed…
```

What am I doing wrong on my workstation or in my Postgres configuration? Thanks!

Edit: Here is what Postgresql looks like in Navicat.

[image: Navicat for Postgresql]

Comment: Thanks Vesevolod. Unfortunately, setting it to false didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you connect to it using some other tool?

Comment: Yes, Navicat. I am using the administrative password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that no db objects were granted to the username above. Once I did this, all went well. Hope this helps someone else.